# Determine all $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$ for which the equation $(a^2+b^2)x^2-2(b^2+c^2)x-(c^2+a^2)=0$ has rational roots.

Tags: quadratics

Determine all $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$ for which the equation $(a^2+b^2)x^2-2(b^2+c^2)x-(c^2+a^2)=0$ has rational roots.. I know $\Delta \ge 0$ and $\sqrt{\Delta}$ must be rational.

Comment: Okay, so what does $\Delta$ mean in this situation?

Comment: =$4(b^2+c^2)^2+4(a^2+b^2)(c^2+a^2)$

Comment: Okay, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don;t know how to start

Comment: Okay, so you have the discriminant (kinda) wrong, the last binomial term should be $(-c^2 - a^2) or the 4 should be negative.

Comment: Oops, meant to be $(-c^2 - a^2)$.

Comment: delta=4(a^4+b^4+c^+a^2b^2+a^2c^2+3b^2c^2). I dont think the polynomial in paranthese can be perfect square or a forth power of an integer .

Comment: $\Delta=4(a^4+b^4+c^4+a^2b^2+a^2c^2+3b^2c^2)$. Iff this number is a perfect square integer then roots will be rational.

Comment: If any two of $a,b,c$ are equal to zero, then there are rational roots.

Answer (score 1):

This is partial solution.

As [Χpẘ suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071810/determine-all-a-b-c-in-mathbbz-for-which-the-equation-a2b2x2-2b2c#comment4615207_2071810), we need to determine $a,b,c$ which makes $a^4+b^4+c^4+a^2b^2+a^2c^2+3b^2c^2$ perfect square. We know that $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2=a^4+b^4+c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2$ is a square.

We know that $(a,0,0), (0,b,0), (0,0,c)$ is solution. Therefore, let's assume that at most one of $a,b,c$ is $0$. Also, we are dealing with squares, so we can assume that $a,b,c$ is all non-negative. Since if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution, then $(kx,ky,kz)$ is also a solution, we may assume $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$. Also, the equation is symmetric with respect to $b$ and $c$, so we may assume that $b \ge c$.

**Case 1:** $a^4+b^4+c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2 = a^4+b^4+c^4+a^2b^2+a^2c^2+3b^2c^2$

If then, $(b^2-a^2)(c^2-a^2)=a^4$. If $a=0$, there is no solution since $b,c$ is nonzero. Similarly, we cannot assume that $b$ or $c$ is zero.

Also if $c \le b < a$, then $0>b^2-a^2>-a^2$ and $0>c^2-a^2>-a^2$, so no solution. If $c \le a \le b$, then LHS is $0$ or negative. Therefore $a<c\le b$.

Let $b^2-a^2=\frac{p}{q}a^2$ and $c^2-a^2=\frac{q}{p}a^2$. Clearly $p \ne q$ and from $b \ge c$, $p > q$. Then we know that both $\frac{p+q}{q}$ and $\frac{p+q}{p}$ are perfect squares, also their reciprocals $\frac{q}{p+q}$ and $\frac{p}{p+q}$. Their sum is exactly $1$ and we know all nontrivial rational solutions to this equation corresponds to Pythagorean triple. Therefore, take any Pythagorean triple $l,m,n$ with $l^2+m^2=n^2$ and $l<m<n$, we have $b^2l^2=a^2n^2$ and $c^2m^2=a^2n^2$. It follows that $a=lm$, $b=mn$, $c=ln$.

**Case 2:** $a^4+b^4+c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2 \ne a^4+b^4+c^4+a^2b^2+a^2c^2+3b^2c^2$

This case is really hard... I cannot make any progress worth mentioning.

---

I made a computer search for the solutions under 1k of Case 2. There are about 760 solutions, and you can see the list and code used here.

```
def is_square(apositiveint):
    x = apositiveint // 2
    seen = set([x])
    while x * x != apositiveint:
        x = (x + (apositiveint // x)) // 2
        if x in seen: return False
        seen.add(x)
    return True

for i in range(0, 1000):
    for j in range(0, 1000):
        for k in range(j, 1000):
            number = i ** 4 + j ** 4 + k ** 4 + 3 * j * j * k * k + i * i * (j * j + k * k)
            if number > 2 and not (i == j == 0 or j == k == 0 or k == i == 0) and is_square(number) and (i * i + j * j + k * k) ** 2 != number:
                print i, j, k, (number ** 0.5 - (i * i + j * j + k * k)) / 18
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gij-LfwLYKCq5TnYlRtDnbem988Udu6zZU-a7iGMjtY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ugh, this doesn't deserve bounty...

Comment: Your response was the only one that came. Come on, this problem is extremely hard for even experienced mathematicians to solve. You tried, but my bounty was about to end, so I had to award it to you.

Comment: So `i` represents $a$, `j` represents $b$ and `k` represents $c$?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue yes.